# How to group invoices by total amount and line number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table look like this:

[image]

I want to auto fill group invoice number if `totord` accumulation is about 20,000,000 or count distinct `invtid` maximum is 16. the grouped invoice has to contain all rows of an order or that order will be eliminated. The grouped invoice number will be reset by `promdate`. Please help me to create a query or a sample SQL code to do it.

Comment: Please provide examples of the output you require. What does "auto fill group invoice number" mean?

Comment: Auto fill mean that the invoice number will be generated automatically base on two conditions above.

Comment: The sample answer provided below confuses things even further. You say "The grouped invoice number will be reset by promdate" but in your example output promdate values are all the same.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it meets the following guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You may need to investigate GROUP BY and HAVING. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms180199.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The output will look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7b5bF.jpg)

Assume that the invoicenbr 0001, 0002, 0003, 0004 are contented with one or two condition (count distinct invtid maximum is 16 or total invoice is 20,000,000).

Comment: Is this an answer to your question or clarification? If clarification, then you should not post it as answer, you need to edit your original question and add additional information.